# Reading SharedPreferences: update on OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener or access directly?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

Tried to search but didn't find a satisfying answer to my question, although it seems a bit trivial.

My app has settings the user can modify. My main activity uses these settings all the time, for example, which image to pop-up on certain events, sound/mute and so on. The settings are saved using `SharedPreference`.

What would be the best (efficient) way to access these settings? I'm familiar with two options:

1. Read it every time I need it from the `SharedPreference` instance using **getInt**, **getString** or **getBoolean**.
   By `SharedPreference` instance I mean the one I set during main activity `onCreate`:

   ```
   mSharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   ```
2. Hold class members on main activity and update them when the user changes the settings, using:

   ```
   public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
   ```

Comment: If you want to keep that settings permanently in your app and you want the Activity to use those settings when your app launches next time. Got with your 1st option. Storing them as class members and holding them only makes sense if you want it temporary.

Comment: Thank you, @HardikTrivedi. wouldn't it be slow to read the settings often with getInt, getString etc.?

Comment: No, shared preferences are loaded into memory when app launched. OS takes care of parsing that xml. It's not you parse XML every time you want to read